# Angular 6: http.get() возвращает 404

Tags: http, typescript, angular

Есть API, по такому запросу приходит некий JSON (из браузера или сваггера все норм)

> http://localhost:2189/api/search/queries?query=s

Но при вызове его из angular, возвращает 404 с body

> Collection 'search' not found

Метод angular

```
headers = new HttpHeaders().set('accept', 'application/json');
params = new HttpParams().set('query', 's');
gettest() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:2189/api/search/queries', {params: this.params, headers: this.headers });
  }
```

Где-то вычитал, что подход с передачей парметров типа `?query=q` не пройдет, но и вынесение в параметры ничего не дало. Что здесь не так?

Comment: во-первых `headers` указывать не нужно, по стандарту и так `json` идет, во-вторых это не проблема angular, вы используете `angular-in-memory-web-api`?

Comment: Артур, спасибо в очередной раз) Да, косяк был имено в angular-in-memory-web-api. Для начала использовал его, а как решил перейти на реальный api выпилить in-memory забыл. Сейчас из импортов убрал и все норм